# Proper 50% chance random number generator implementation for player

Tags: c#, node.js, random

I am playing with some demo of rolling a dice in javascript, where i select 3 numbers out of 6 and use following snippet to get the random result:

```
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1); // Random number between 1 and 6
```

this is global random, meaning that one player can have much higher win rate than 50% and other lower etc.

How would I implement something that would keep every players win rate exactly towards 50% and not higher? At the moment I am experiencing having huge win strikes while I am rolling, which would mean that in real life that would be the same case, so how would I limit myself to never exceed for example 55% win rate and if it does should slowly go towards 50%, and vice versa if going below 50%?

Is there any api service, that when i provide the ID for player, it would keep the count of wins and losses and keep the rate of win around 50%? Aka keep the historical data for the user etc and decide on win/loss ratio what next number would be by knowing the roll before, but if 50 win /50 losses would do honest random roll. This would destroy win strike though i guess.

So I think I would have to do something like:

- if win/loss ratio is 50%, do legit random rolls until 51%, then decide against player to go back to 50% of win/rate. I know this wouldn't be honest but are there any other honest ways to really keep 50% of randomization by just running the snippet above?

Comment: Give each player their own random number generator with different seed. In nodejs, it could be sharding.

Comment: About the last point, as the inspiration you may want to dig into pseudo random generation mechanism used in Dota2 (originally, Warcraft III): https://liquipedia.net/dota2/Pseudo_Random_Distribution

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik do you have any example of that? sounds very interesting.

Comment: @sensei normally sharding is only for few processes but if performance is not the concern, there could be a few hundred (or even thousands) of processes with just some micro-service of their own (for each player). Maybe very bad performance but the latency of thread-switching should be hidden if dice rolls are not frequent. Also you can have a C++ application for high-performance multi-player random number generation that is called from command-line by nodejs and communicate via ramdisk or just i/o (stdin stdout). It would need some state-saving between process calls with some database or file

Answer (score 1):

How long are those win-strikes? When I test this:

```
console.log(Math.random());
```

I get four or five values in a row that are bigger than 0.5 then one below 0.5 then another bigger than 0.5. If this is a problem for game logic, then you don't need random numbers but plot-armor. If you use only one random number generator for all players, then of course some players can steal another player's "destiny" and those players can have very bad or very good dice rolls.

To overcome the issue of "fairness" between players, you can have a unique seed for each player's random number generator. This is possible (and fast) in C++. Calling a compiled C++ console program from Node-js is easy. The only issue would be optimizing it for millions of concurrent players. C++'s `std::mt19937` is fast enough and takes a seed value (from os too).

Since you tagged C#, same thing can be done within C# too.`new Random(some random seed here)` should give similar results. Then you can host the algorithm as a micro-service and make it accessed by nodejs (assuming main backend part of app is on nodejs).

Lastly, you can have one micro-service process per player for the RND. This should give everyone their own seeds for random number generations. But too many players would mean too many threads which is very bad for performance unless dice-rolls are very rare. For example,I can start 100 processes on my 8 core cpu with this:

```
"use strict";

var cluster = require('cluster');
if(cluster.isMaster){for(let i=0;i<100;i++) { cluster.fork(); }}

console.log(Math.random());
```

but it starts very slow and hosting a RND server per process could be even slower. So, only main process should host the RND service and internally communicate with worker processes. Cluster module of NodeJs lets worker processes communicate with main process. Pure event-driven communication (no spin-wait whatsoever) between worker(RND) processes and main process should be CPU-friendly but still if all of (millions of) players throw dices at the same time then the process/thread-switching overhead would be visible and each process takes certain amount of memory so the RAM capacity becomes important too. There are custom random number generators for NodeJs that can take seed for much less CPU/RAM usage.

Comment: Thanks huseyin for such a long answer. When you say unique seed for each players RNG, should it be unique per player, always the same, or unique in a sense it should be each time different, let's say timestamp + unique player identifier + some salt) ?

Comment: By unique seed I meant starting/initialization value of each generator. It could be timestamp or anything with enough realism illusion.

Comment: Aha so each time player 1 rolls it would have different seed, one fixed seed is not bound to player 1, and next seed for player 2, but literally every seed should be different for player 1 each roll(example would be timestamp or epoch + some random string each time), to avoid unreal streak of 10 in a row, is that what you say? because for example if one player bets $100 and has 10 streak it's $1000, but other player bets $10 and has 10 streak losses, it does equal in probability, but house is in $900 loss. So i am trying to eliminate these crazy streaks.  You've been great help so far, thanks.